# String Replace in csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Below, I am trying to replace data in a csv. The code works, but it replaces anything matching `stocklevel`in the file.

```
def updatestocklevel(quantity, stocklevel, code):
    newlevel = stocklevel - quantity
    stocklevel = str(stocklevel)
    newlevel = str(newlevel)
    s = open("stockcontrol.csv").read()
    s = s.replace (stocklevel ,newlevel) #be careful - will currently replace any number in the file matching stock level!
    f = open("stockcontrol.csv", 'w')
    f.write(s)
    f.close()
```

My csv looks like this;

```
34512340,1
12395675,2
56756777,1
90673412,2
12568673,3
22593672,5
65593691,4
98593217,2
98693214,2
98693399,5
11813651,85
98456390,8
98555567,3
98555550,45
98553655,2
96553657,1
91823656,2
99823658,2
```

Elsewhere in my program, I have a function that searches for the code (8 digits)
Is it possible to say, if the `code` is in the line of the csv, replace the data in the second column? (data[2])

Comment: Where is that "CSV"? CSV stands for "comma separated values", right?

Comment: Yes, the comma is after the 8 digit code on each line. I just copied from excel @MarcusMüller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the occurances of `stocklevel` are getting replaced with the value of `newlevel` as you are calling `s.replace (stocklevel ,newlevel)`.

> **string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace]):** Return a copy of string s
>   with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional
>   argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are
>   replaced.

[source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

As you suggested, you need to get the `code` and use it replace the stock level.

This is a sample script which takes the 8 digit code and the new stock level as the command line arguments adn replaces it:

```
import sys
import re
code = sys.argv[1]
newval= int(sys.argv[2]) 
f=open("stockcontrol.csv")
data=f.readlines()
print data
for i,line in enumerate(data):
  if re.search('%s,\d+'%code,line): # search for the line with 8-digit code
    data[i]  = '%s,%d\n'%(code,newval) # replace the stock value with new value in the same line
f.close()

f=open("in.csv","w")
f.write("".join(data))
print data
f.close()
```

Another solution using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module of Python:

```
import sys
import csv

data=[]
code = sys.argv[1]
newval= int(sys.argv[2])
f=open("stockcontrol.csv")
reader=csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames=['code','level'])
for line in reader:
  if line['code'] == code:
    line['level']= newval
  data.append('%s,%s'%(line['code'],line['level']))
f.close()

f=open("stockcontrol.csv","w")
f.write("\n".join(data))
f.close()
```

**Warning:** Keep a back up of the input file while trying out these scripts as they overwrite the input file.

If you save the script in a file called `test.py` then invoke it as:

`python test.py 34512340 10`.

This should replace the stockvalue of code 34512340 to 10.

Comment: Both of these come up with the error ' code = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: @NathanShoesmith, you need to call it this way `python <script> <code_to_be_modified> <newstockvalue>`

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean @SilentMonk ? Can you show me in the code please?

Comment: @NathanShoesmith, I have edited the answer suggesting how to invoke it.

Comment: Okay @SilentMonk , I have saved the code as test.py, but what do you mean by invoke it??

Comment: @NathanShoesmith You have saved one of the two scripts right? Invoke means execute. Do this -  `python test.py 34512340 10`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113344/discussion-between-nathan-shoesmith-and-silentmonk).

Comment: Please can you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729969/string-replace-for-multiple-lines-in-a-csv It's a progression on this answer and I think you'll probably be able to answer it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a csv file I'd suggest using Python's `csv` module. You will need to write to a new file since reading and writing to the same file will turn out bad. You can always rename it afterwards.

This example uses `StringIO` (Python 2) to embed your csv data in the code and treat it as a file. Normally you would open a file to get the input.

**Updated**

```
import csv
# Python 2 and 3
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO


CSV = """\
34512340,1
12395675,2
56756777,1
90673412,2
12568673,3
22593672,5
65593691,4
98593217,2
98693214,2
98693399,5
11813651,85
98456390,8
98555567,3
98555550,45
98553655,2
96553657,1
91823656,2
99823658,2
"""


def replace(key, value):
    fr = StringIO(CSV)
    with open('out.csv', 'w') as fw:
        r = csv.reader(fr)
        w = csv.writer(fw)

        for row in r:
            if row[0] == key:
                row[1] = value
            w.writerow(row)

replace('99823658', 42)
```

Comment: 'no module named StringIO'

Comment: @NathanShoesmith Updated with python3.x support.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using good old regular expressions?

```
import re

code, new_value = '11813651', '885' # e.g, change 85 to 885 for code 11813651
print (re.sub('(^%s,).*'%code,'\g<1>'+new_value,open('stockcontrol.csv').read()))
```

Comment: You can pipe the output to the same file at the command line or just use `print (re.sub('(^%s,).*'%code,'\g<1>'+new_value,open('stockcontrol.csv').read()),file=open('stockcontrol.csv','w'))` instead.