# String Replace for Multiple Lines In A CSV

Tags: python, csv

Below is a snippet from a csv file. The first column is the product number, 2 is the stock level, 3 is the target level, and 4 is the distance from target (target minus stock level.)

```
34512340,0,95,95
12395675,3,95,92
56756777,70,95,25
90673412,2,95,93
```

When the stock level gets to 5 or below, I want to have the stock levels updated from python when a user requests it.

I am currently using this piece of code which I have adapted from just updating one line in the CSV. It isn't working though. The first line is written back to the file as `34512340,0,95,95` and the rest of the file is deleted.

```
    choice = input("\nTo update the stock levels of the above products, type 1. To cancel, enter anything else.")
if choice == '1':
    with open('stockcontrol.csv',newline='') as f:
        for line in f:
            data = line.split(",")
            productcode = int(data[0])
            target = int(data[2])
            stocklevel = int(data[1])
            if stocklevel <= 5:
                target = str(target)
                import sys
                import csv
                data=[]
                newval= target
                newtlevel = "0"
                f=open("stockcontrol.csv")
                reader=csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames=['code','level', 'target', 'distancefromtarget'])
                for line in reader:
                    line['level']= newval
                    line['distancefromtarget']= newtlevel
                    data.append('%s,%s,%s,%s'%(line['code'],line['level'],line['target'],line['distancefromtarget']))
                    f.close()
                    f=open("stockcontrol.csv","w")
                    f.write("\n".join(data))
                    f.close()
                    print("The stock levels were updated successfully")
else:
    print("Goodbye")
```

Here is the code that I had changing one line in the CSV file and works:

```
with open('stockcontrol.csv',newline='') as f:
            for line in f:
                if code in line:
                    data = line.split(",")
                    target = (data[2])
    newlevel = stocklevel - quantity
    updatetarget = int(target) - int(newlevel)
    stocklevel = str(stocklevel)
    newlevel = str(newlevel)
    updatetarget = str(updatetarget)
    import sys
    import csv

    data=[]
    code = code
    newval= newlevel
    newtlevel = updatetarget
    f=open("stockcontrol.csv")
    reader=csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames=['code','level', 'target', 'distancefromtarget'])
    for line in reader:
      if line['code'] == code:
        line['level']= newval
        line['distancefromtarget']= newtlevel
      data.append('%s,%s,%s,%s'%(line['code'],line['level'],line['target'],line['distancefromtarget']))
    f.close()

    f=open("stockcontrol.csv","w")
    f.write("\n".join(data))
    f.close()
```

What can I change to make the code work? I basically want the program to loop through each line of the CSV file, and if the stock level (column 2) is equal to or less than 5, update the stock level to the target number in column 3, and then set the number in column 4 to zero.

Thanks,

Comment: @SilentMonk please can you look at this question

Comment: Apologies, yes it did @SilentMonk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code reads each line and checks the value of column 2. If it is less than or equal to 5, the value of column2 is changed to value of column3 and last column is changed to 0 else all the columns are left unchanged.

```
import sys
import csv

data=[]
f=open("stockcontrol.csv")
reader=csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames=['code','level','target','distancefromtarget'])
for line in reader:
  if int(line['level']) <= 5:
    line['level']= line['target']
    line['distancefromtarget']= 0
  data.append("%s,%s,%s,%s"%(line['code'],line['level'],line['target'],line['distancefromtarget']))
f.close()


f=open("stockcontrol.csv","w")
f.write("\n".join(data))
f.close()
```

Coming to issues in your code:

You are first reading the file without using the `csv` module and getting the values in each column by splitting the line. You are again using the `DictReader` method of `csv` module to read the values you already had.